# Python markdown edge case: /* */

Tags: python, markdown

Is there a way to get Python to interpret Markdown the same way as it is interpreted here on stackoverflow:

> This is a C comment: /* */ tada!

and on github? https://gist.github.com/jason-s/fc81280dc6108f9ec3a8

Python's markdown module interprets the `* *` as italics:

```
>>> import markdown
>>> markdown.markdown('This is a C comment: /* */ tada!')
u'<p>This is a C comment: /<em> </em>/ tada!</p>'
```

([Babelmark 2 shows some of the differences.](http://johnmacfarlane.net/babelmark2/?text=This+is+a+C+comment%3A+%2F*+*%2F+tada!) Looks like there are different interpretations of the markdown syntax.)

Comment: (aside from special-casing this and using `/\* \*/`)

Comment: Jakob: Yes, I know. I'm just dealing with someone who put a lot of text in comments in Stash (which also behaves like stackoverflow and github markdown) without doing the escaping with backticks, and I've got a Python script that I wrote which special-formats the results, and it doesn't produce the same HTML output that Stash produces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/* */` syntax is not standard Markdown. In fact, it is not mentioned at all in the [syntax rules](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax). Therefore, it is less likely to be handled consistently among different Markdown implementations.

If it is a C comment, then it is "code" and should probably be marked up as such. Either in a code block or using inline code backticks (`` `/* */` ``). As mentioned in a comment to the OP, it could also be escaped with backslashes if you really don't want it marked up as code. Personally, I would instruct the author to fix their documents (regardless of parser behavior).

In fact, the Markdown parsers that do ignore it do so by accident. In an effort to avoid matching a few edge cases that should not be interpreted as emphasis, they require a word boundary before the opening asterisk (but not after it) and a word boundary after the closing asterisk (but not before it) to consider is as emphasis. Because the C comment has a slash before the opening asterisk (and a space after it) and a slash after the closing asterisk (and a space before it), some parsers do not see it as emphasis. I suspect you will find that those same parsers fail to identify a few edge cases as emphasis that should be. And as the Syntax Rules are silent on these edge cases, each implementation gets them slightly different. I would even go so far as to say that the implementations that do not see that as emphasis are potentially in the wrong here. But this is not the place to debate that.

That said, you  are using Python-Markdown, which has a comprehensive [Extension API](https://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/extensions/api.html). If an existing [third party extension](https://github.com/waylan/Python-Markdown/wiki/Third-Party-Extensions) does not already exist (see below), you can [create your own](https://github.com/waylan/Python-Markdown/wiki/Tutorial:-Writing-Extensions-for-Python-Markdown). You may add your own pattern to match the C comment specifically and handle it however you like. Or you may override the parser's default handling of emphasis and make it match some other implementation who's behavior you desire.

Actually, the [BetterEm](http://facelessuser.github.io/PyMdown/extensions/betterem/) Extension (which, for some reason is not on the list of third party extensions) might do the later and give you the behavior you want. Unfortunately, it does not ship by itself, but as part of a [larger package](https://github.com/facelessuser/pymdown-extensions) which includes multiple extensions. Of course, you only need to use the one. To get it working you need to install it. Unfortunately, it does not appear to be hosted on PyPI, so you'll have to download it directly from GitHub. The following command should download and install it all in one go:

```
pip install https://github.com/facelessuser/pymdown-extensions/archive/master.zip
```

Once you have successfully installed it just do the following in Python:

```
>>> import markdown
>>> html = markdown.markdown(yourtext, extensions=['pymdownx.betterem'])
```

Or from the commandline:

```
python -m markdown -x 'pymdownx.betterem' yourinputfile.md > output.html
```

**Note:** I have not tested the BetterEm Extension. It may or may not give you the behavior you want. According to the docs, "the behavior will be very similar in feel to GFM bold and italic (but not necessarily exact)."

Comment: @Jason S, just curious if the the BetterEm Extension works for you. Haven't used it myself and am wondering if it addresses your issue.

Answer (score 0):

well, it's ugly, but this post-Markdown-processing patch seems to do what I want.

```
>>> import markdown
>>> mdtext = 'This is a C comment: /* */ tada!'
>>> mdhtml = markdown.markdown(mdtext)
>>> mdhtml
u'<p>This is a C comment: /<em> </em>/ tada!</p>'
>>> import re
>>> mdccommentre = re.compile('/<em>( | .* )</em>/')
>>> mdccommentre.sub('/*\\1*/',mdhtml)
u'<p>This is a C comment: /* */ tada!</p>'
```